# How to list file names on a remote unix server in r?

Tags: r

I created a session and can execute the ls command

```
library(ssh)
session<-ssh_connect("someuser@x.x.x.x", keyfile = "my private key")
ssh_exec_wait(session, command = 'ls /home/')
```

This results of the ls command displayed in rstudio console and the function returns 0.

So this does not work

```
varFileList<-ssh_exec_wait(session, command = 'ls /home/')
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer

```
varFileList<-capture.output(ssh_exec_wait(session, command = 'ls /home/'))
```